# String tokens in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am writing a app in .NET which will generate random text based on some input. So if I have text like `"I love your {lovely|nice|great} dress"` I want to choose randomly from `lovely/nice/great` and use that in text. Any suggestions in C# or VB.NET are welcome.

Comment: Is there a possibility of nested {,}, or | characters in the replaced data?  If not, are you _sure_?  It makes a huge difference in the possible solutions.

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with? Please provide the code you have so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do it using a regex to make a replacement for each `{...}`. The [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) function can take a [`MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) which can do the logic for selecting a random value from the choices:

```
Random random = new Random();
string s = "I love your {lovely|nice|great} dress";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\{(.*?)\}", match => {
    string[] options = match.Groups[1].Value.Split('|');
    int index = random.Next(options.Length);
    return options[index];
});
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Example output:

```
I love your lovely dress
```

---

Update: Translated to VB.NET automatically using [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/):

```
Dim random As New Random
Dim s As String = "I love your {lovely|nice|great} dress"
s = Regex.Replace(s, "\{(.*?)\}", Function (ByVal match As Match) 
    Dim options As String() = match.Groups.Item(1).Value.Split(New Char() { "|"c })
    Dim index As Integer = random.Next(options.Length)
    Return options(index)
End Function)
```

Comment: would it be possible to convert this code to vb.net ? it seems that it will perfectly suit my needs

Comment: +1 this is similar to how I've solved this before. I thought this looked familiar, more so now after the VB request (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/regexp/thread/51628ff3-23f9-4de5-bf42-1baef802b8c7) - makes me wonder if this is h/w. My pattern differed slightly to ensure a `|` but `.*?` works just as well :)

Comment: @julio, @Mark: you might already know this but multi-statement lambdas were introduced in VB10 (unlike C# which had it earlier). I can't test the translation at the moment but wanted to point that out (Reflector might not be accurate). I had used `AddressOf` instead and broke it out as its own method for the `MatchEvaluator`. For VB10+ a multi-statement lambda is the way to go.

Comment: @julio glad that helped but please consider marking @Mark's reply as the answer since he had the right solution that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit of an abuse of the custom formatting functionality available through the ICustomFormatter and IFormatProvider interfaces, but you could do something like this:

```
public class ListSelectionFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    #region IFormatProvider Members

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (typeof(ICustomFormatter).IsAssignableFrom(formatType))
            return this;
        else
            return null;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICustomFormatter Members

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        string[] values = format.Split('|');

        if (values == null || values.Length == 0)
            throw new FormatException("The format is invalid.  At least one value must be specified.");
        if (arg is int)
            return values[(int)arg];
        else if (arg is Random)
            return values[(arg as Random).Next(values.Length)];
        else if (arg is ISelectionPicker)
            return (arg as ISelectionPicker).Pick(values);
        else
            throw new FormatException("The argument is invalid.");
    }

    #endregion
}

public interface ISelectionPicker
{
    string Pick(string[] values);
}

public class RandomSelectionPicker : ISelectionPicker
{
    Random rng = new Random();

    public string Pick(string[] values)
    {
        // use whatever logic is desired here to choose the correct value
        return values[rng.Next(values.Length)];
    }
}

class Stuff
{
    public static void DoStuff()
    {
        RandomSelectionPicker picker = new RandomSelectionPicker();
        string result = string.Format(new ListSelectionFormatter(), "I am feeling {0:funky|great|lousy}.  I should eat {1:a banana|cereal|cardboard}.", picker, picker);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Format("static text {0} more text {1}", randomChoice0, randomChoice1);
```

Comment: this seems the easiest way but I will probably have to use more than 3 "tokens" in the string and string.format does not allow more than three

Comment: I think you're mistaken.  String.Format() takes an arbitrary number of parameters/tokens.  'String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", 0, 1, 2, 3)' results in '0123' without any errors.

Comment: i meant i might need to use String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", 0, 1, 2, 3,4,5)' which won't work

Comment: Have you even tried this?  I just did, and successfully got the string '012345' without any errors.  In fact, I also successfully tried 'String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'a')'.

Comment: sorry, I was relying on intellisense which made me thing only 3 arguments can be used

Answer (score 0):

write a simple parser that will get the information in the braces, split it with `string.Split` , get a random index for that array and build up the string again.

use the `StringBuilder` for building the result due to performance issues with other stringoperations.